# How to v-for checked value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-for

I'm trying to create a checkbox select only one.

```
<div id="app">
 <div v-for="(question, index) in questions">
   <input type="checkbox" value="question.value" v-model="additional_grouped"  @change="uniqueCheck"> {{question.title}}
  </div>
  {{ result }}
</div>
```

My JS looks like the following:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      additional: [],
      additional_grouped: [],
       questions: [
         {
           title: 'A',
           value: 0
         },
         {
           title: 'B',
           value: 1
         },
         {
           title: 'C',
           value: 2
         }
       ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    result: function(){
      return this.additional.concat(this.additional_grouped);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    uniqueCheck(e){
      console.log(e)
      this.additional_grouped = [];
      if (e.target.checked) {
          this.additional_grouped.push(e.target.value);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

This is the old result.

[image]

I'm trying to get results like this.

[image]

**I can do this by not the v-for method, but I want to do it this way. Because I have a lot of data, How can I checked value in v-for?**

Here is my pen: [enter link description here](https://codepen.io/puthxii/pen/qBZLzMr?editors=1010)

Comment: Can you not just change your logic to not concat the values to the array, and instead just keep one value?

Comment: Apparently I misread this question.  "I'm trying to create a checkbox select only one." made me think you were trying to change a multi select into a single select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the value binding (`:value`), here's your example fixed:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      additional: [],
      additional_grouped: [],
       questions: [
         {
           title: 'A',
           value: 0
         },
         {
           title: 'B',
           value: 1
         },
         {
           title: 'C',
           value: 2
         }
       ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    result: function(){
      return this.additional.concat(this.additional_grouped);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    uniqueCheck(e){
      this.additional_grouped = [];
      if (e.target.checked) {
          this.additional_grouped.push(e.target.value);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
 <div v-for="(question, index) in questions">
   <input type="checkbox" :value="question.value" v-model="additional_grouped"  @change="uniqueCheck"> {{question.title}}
  </div>
  {{ result }}
</div>
```

[Documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html)

Answer (score 1):

uses `:value="question.value"` instead of `value="question.value"`

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      additional: [],
      additional_grouped: [],
       questions: [
         {
           title: 'A',
           value: 0
         },
         {
           title: 'B',
           value: 1
         },
         {
           title: 'C',
           value: 2
         }
       ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    result: function(){
      return this.additional.concat(this.additional_grouped);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    uniqueCheck(e){
      this.additional_grouped = [];
      if (e.target.checked) {
          this.additional_grouped.push(e.target.value);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
 <div v-for="(question, index) in questions">
   <input type="checkbox" :value="question.value" v-model="additional_grouped"  @change="uniqueCheck"> {{question.title}}
  </div>
  {{ result }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get an array of the values of checked boxes, you should just do this

```
<div id="app">
 <div v-for="(question, index) in questions" :key="index">
   <input type="checkbox" v-model="question.checked"> {{question.title}}
  </div>
  {{ result }}
</div>
```

and

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
       questions: [
         {
           title: 'A',
           value: 0
         },
         {
           title: 'B',
           value: 1
         },
         {
           title: 'C',
           value: 2
         }
       ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    result: function(){
      return this.questions.filter(q => q.checked).map(q => q.value)
    }
  }
});
```